# Uninterpreted strings in YAML

Tags: python, yaml

Is there a way to have uninterpreted strings within a YAML file?  My goal is to have regular expressions that contain certain escape sequences like `\w`.  Currently, Python's YAML complains: `found unknown escape character 'w'`.

I know I could escape them, but this is going to obfuscate the actual regular expression.  Any way around this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816236/loading-document-as-raw-string-in-yaml-with-pyyaml, basically, each type of quotes has pros and cons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using [literal scalar syntax](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#literal%20style/syntax)?

Comment: I'm having a horrid time reading those docs - do you have an example?

Comment: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=just_don't_quote%3A+foo%5Cwbar%0A%0Aliteral_scalar%3A+|%0A++++%22foo%5Cwbar%22%0A++++for+if+you+need+quotes%0A%0Afolded_scalar%3A+%3E%0A++++%22foo%5Cwbar%22%0A++++for+if+you+need+quotes+but+not+new&type=python

Answer (score 16):

Appears that using single quotes doesn't interpret the escaped characters.

E.g.,

```
key1: [ 'tron' ]
key2: [ 'not/escaped/[\w-]*/.*' ]
```

Works.